# What kind of cheap, available, magnetic metal could I use for my boardgame?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, metals

My question revolves around my need to snap plaster walls to plaster dungeon floors for a boardgame called Dungeons & Dragons. My intention is to glue and paint over metallic strips under the walls and when casting using plaster, the floors you see in the image below, get a nice system where I can just snap walls in place to my liking.

I am looking for a metal that responds very well to magnetic waves (the magnetic sheets are pretty weak) and resists the passage of time. By that I mean resist rusting, corrosion, etc.

I  am also looking for availability, as in easy to find and cut/manipulate. I may have excluded iron because its easy for it to rust, I think.

The picture below is a typical setup for a "dungeon". Its very easy to knock down the walls because they are tall and very lightweight. When we play, we move miniature monsters and heroes and keep putting the walls back on over and over; it decreases the fun quite a lot.

[image]

Comment: While cool, this question seems a much better fit for the DIY Stack Exchange site than the Physics Stack Exchange site.

Comment: The architecture firm that is overseeing the redesign of the science building on my campus has exactly these kinds of parts (though in a modern motif, obviously). Unfortunately I believe they are specialty products (and they may 3d print some of their own). That said, many cheap whiteboards have a magnetic backing, so you just embed small magnets (which can be purchased in bulk for very little) in the bottoms of the parts and away you go. Have access to a 3d printer?